# QTest implementation

Tags: qt, qtestlib

How can I use the QTest::setBenchmarkResult method? I want an example of it. I have used this code:

```
QBENCHMARK{
    // Some code here ...
}
```

I want to catch the result of the benchmark and with a especific metric.

Comment: Use QTest::setBenchmarkResult() if you want to report benchmark results **without** using the QBENCHMARK macro.

Comment: why do you need catch result of benchmark? It is printed in report (user readable form or xml). `setBenchmarkResult` is to report results when you are providing own version of benchmark code.

Comment: How can I store in form or xml file, the results of the QBENCHMARK macro?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see example from the documentation:

```
void TestBenchmark::simple()
{
    QString str1 = QLatin1String("This is a test string");
    QString str2 = QLatin1String("This is a test string");

    QCOMPARE(str1.localeAwareCompare(str2), 0);

    QBENCHMARK {
        str1.localeAwareCompare(str2);
    }
}
```

Is it what you need?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use the QTest::setBenchmarkResult method?

You can use it to report a benchmark-metric result-value that you **calculated yourself**:

```
class CustomTimerBenchmark : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    void BenchmarkNanosecondsWithCustomTimer()
    {
        MyCustomTimer myCustomTimer;
        timer.start();

        // here goes benchmarked code

        QTest::setBenchmarkResult(
            myCustomTimer.nanoseconds(), QTest::WalltimeNanoseconds);
        // ^^^^
        // This will treat BenchmarkNanosecondsWithCustomTimer
        // as benchmark that reports wall-time in nanoseconds
    }
};
```

> I want to catch the result of the benchmark and with a especific
>   metric.

You can not do it with `QTest::setBenchmarkResult`